# PHPExcel not writing last cells with formula

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel 1.7.8 on PHP 5.6 to export an Excel file from a database table.

If the result set is something lower than 20.000 rows, the totals line with the totals formulas appear.

If the result set is bigger than 20.000, the totals cells with the formulas don't appear and neither does the background color.

This is the code generating the last line with the totals:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B' . $i, Yii::t('asientos_excel_diario', 'TOTALES'));

$formula = '=SUM(' . "M{$pos_ini_suma_totales}:M" . $ultima_fila . ')';
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M' . $i, $formula);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('M' . $i)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');

$formula = '=SUM(' . "N{$pos_ini_suma_totales}:N" . $ultima_fila . ')';
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('N' . $i, $formula);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('N' . $i)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A5:N5')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFA0A0A0');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A' . $i . ':' . 'N' . $i)->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFA0A0A0');
```

If I simply remove the "=" from the formula (so instead a formula I have a plain string), the cells content ant background show up.

[image]

But if I leave the formula on, they appear as blank cells:

[image]

And then, if I limit the DB results from 30k to let's say 15k, the cells do show up and the formula works properly:

[image]

I really don't know into what kind of limitation or bug I'm running but it doesn't make too much sense.

Other than that, I'm writing the file using this:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Maybe I will try next also with different versions of PHPExcel library, or try to reproduce write an isolated example from scratch in another place and see if it behaves the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve it by changing the writer's format of the output file:

From this:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
```

To this:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
```

And now the totals cells were properly generated with both background and formula.